# Typing Greek name with accent without unicode

Tags: greek

How to write "Apollonius" in ancient greek in LaTeX without solutions based on unicode?

I do not know the exact situation, as I was indirectly asked about this. Some user can not (or want not?) to use UTF-8 encoding. He/she should write the name of Apollonius in ancient greek; I suppose that we are talking about this guy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonius_of_Tyana. Using package `textgreek` and saying `...\textlambda\'\textomega...` will put diacritic mark as a separate character, not above omega letter as it should.

Comment: Tell (s)he that nowadays 99.9% people use utf-8 (am I right?)

Comment: I know, but maybe there is a problem setting up charset for ssh connection or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `babel`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[greek.polutoniko,english]{babel}

\begin{document}

Apollonius of Tyana (\textgreek{Ἀπολλώνιος ὁ Τυανεύς})
was a Greek Neopythagorean philosopher, not to be confused
with Apollonius of Perga (\textgreek{Ἀπολλώνιος ὁ Περγαῖος}).

\end{document}
```

[image]

If I copy from the PDF file and paste here, I get

```
ώ
```

You can also use the alternative input

```latex
Apollonius of Tyana (\textgreek{>Apoll'wnios <o Tuane'us})
was a Greek Neopythagorean philosopher, not to be confused
with Apollonius of Perga (\textgreek{>Apoll'wnios <o Perga\~ios}).
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

(Tables from the documentation of `cbfonts`, available with `texdoc cbfonts` on TeX Live.)

Comment: First suggestion relies on unicode, so can't be used in this case. However, the second suggestion work; the user has confirmed this. Thanks (again)!

Comment: @JoriMäntysalo I added the conversion tables